# Is it possible to upload to gcs using file stream buffer in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, google-cloud-storage, multer

I am trying to send `FormData` to NestJS server to upload files to GCS.

When using Multer, I was worried about the following problems.

1. If Multer stores the temp file locally, additional server costs are incurred to store it locally.
2. When Multer stores files in memory storage, memory may overflow when many users make upload requests large files at the same time.

So I'm considering uploading to gcs using a chunked file stream buffer.

However, when I use the '@google-cloud/storage' package, there is no function related to writeSteam.

```
"@google-cloud/storage": "^6.9.1"
```

Is it not possible to upload to GCS using file stream in NodeJS environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-nodejs). This will allow users to upload files directly to GCS and also supports [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable).

> If Multer stores the temp file locally, additional server costs are incurred to store it locally.

If you do not specify a local destination for the file, it won't be saved to the disk.

> However, when I use the '@google-cloud/storage' package, there is no function related to writeSteam.

There is [`createWriteStream()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) method but the buffer will still use resources before the file is uploaded to GCS.

```
@Controller('gcloud')
export class GcloudController {
  constructor(private readonly gcloudService: GcloudService) {}

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  upload(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    return this.gcloudService.upload(file);
  } 
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class GcloudService {
  async upload(file: Express.Multer.File) {
    const writeStream = storage
      .bucket('<>.appspot.com')
      .file('<>')
      .createWriteStream();

    writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    // use a Promise to return response when file is uploaded 
    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
    });

    writeStream.end(file.buffer);
  }
}
```

Using **signed URLs** might be a better solution in case the files are very large.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to append chunked file bytes to a bucket file?

Comment: And if i do not specify a local destination for the file, are requested files stored in server memory?

Comment: @HyeonjunJeong are you referring to [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#client-libraries)?  When you don't specify local destination, the file won't be saved to local disk. What do mean by 'server memory'? storage?

Comment: I wonder where the server is storing the requested file before sending it to GCS.  
I thought it would be a problem if the client requested a large file and it was storing it in the server's RAM.

The process I want is to slice the file into 1mb on the client side, send it to the server and append it to the bucket file.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the official documentation, i cannot update uploaded file :(

Comment: @HyeonjunJeong that would also be a problem even if many users are trying to upload smaller chunks at the same time then? Signed URLs seems a feasible option here if you know you'll run into these issues.

Comment: Um... if 100 people requested 1GB each at the same time, the server would need up to 100GB of memory. On the other hand, if 100 people request 1MB each, the server only needs to have 100MB in memory because it is allocated in memory when requested and released after 1MB upload processing. Instead, it will increase the number of requests, but the server will not be stopped due to memory overflow. Is this wrong idea?

Comment: On second thought, 100GB is wrong because the server processes requests sequentially :)...

Comment: Sorry for asking again and again! I will try the solution you mentioned.